# How to load PostgreSQL data into GeoMesa (with the Cassandra datastore)?

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, geomesa

I tried to load Postresql data into Geomesa (with a Cassandra datastore), by the JDBC Converter.

Loading from shape works fine, so the Cassandra and GeoMesa setup is okay

Next I tried to load data from PostgreSQL

**Command:**

echo "SELECT year, geom, grondgebruik, crop_code, crop_name, fieldid, global_id, area, perimeter, geohash FROM v_gewaspercelen2018" | bin/geomesa-cassandra ingest -c catalog -P cassandraserver:9042 -k agrodatacube -f parcel -C geomesa.converters.parcel -u  -p

The converter definition file **geomesa.converters.parcel** looks like this:

```
geomesa.converters.parcel = {

type = "jdbc"

connection = "dbc:postgresql://postgresserver:5432/agrodatacube"

id-field="toString($5)"

fields = [

    { name = "fieldid",    transform = "$5"        }

    { name = "global_id",    transform = "$6"        }

    { name = "year",    transform = "$0"         }

    { name = "area",  transform = "$7"        }

    { name = "perimeter",  transform = "$8"         }

    { name = "grondgebruik",   transform = "$2"      }

    { name = "crop_code",    transform = "$3"     }

    { name = "crop_name",   transform = "$4"       }

    { name = "geohash",   transform = "$9"     }

    { name = "geom",   transform = "$1"      }

]
}
```

**The geomesa output is:**

```
INFO  Schema 'parcel' exists

INFO  Running ingestion in local mode

INFO  Ingesting from stdin with 1 thread
[                                                         ]   0% complete 0 i[                                                            ]   0% complete 0 ingested 0 failed in 00:00:01

ERROR Fatal error running local ingest worker on <stdin>

[                                                            ]   0% complete 0 i[                                                            ]   0% complete 0 ingested 0 failed in 00:00:01

INFO  Local ingestion complete in 00:00:01

INFO  Ingested 0 features with no failures for file: <stdin>

WARN  Some files caused errors, ingest counts may not be accurate
```

Does someone have a clue what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can check in the `logs` folder for more detailed errors. However, just at a first glance, the JDBC converter follows [standard result set numbering](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/convert/jdbc.html#transform-functions), meaning the first field is `$1` (not `$0`). In addition, you may need to transform your geometry with a transform function, i.e. `geometry($2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Emilio, both suggestions made sence!

1. Made the converter field count start at 1
2. Inside the converter definition file changed

> { name = "geom",   transform = "$2"      }

into

> { name = "geom",   transform = "geometry($2)"      }

3. The SQL Select command should be:

> SELECT year, **ST_AsText(geom)**, .... FROM v_gewaspercelen2018

By the way, username and password are part of the connection-string (which is inside file geomesa.converters.parcel):

> connection =
>   "dbc:postgresql://postgresserver:5432/agrodatacube?user=username&password=password"

So the -u and -p flags do not appear in the final command:

> echo "SELECT year, ST_AsText(geom), grondgebruik, crop_code,
>   crop_name, fieldid, global_id, area, perimeter, geohash FROM
>   v_gewaspercelen2018" | bin/geomesa-cassandra ingest -c catalog -P
>   cassandraserver:9042 -k agrodatacube -f parcel -C
>   geomesa.converters.parcel

With these changes it works.

Thanks again!

Hugo